# Resizing UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, autoresize

I'm working on the project. Currently I'm facing a problem, I have 3 UITableView's in one ViewController. It looks something like this:
[image]

Now, The first TableView(top one), has just one row, that has a size of 55 pixels and it don;t have to be resizable. Next, second one is the TableView, again with one row, but this row must to resize depends on the content of it. Right now this TableView displaying this row:
[image]

This row must to resize depends on how long the text in it. What I did to calculate the size is:

```
if(tableView == self.usersPostOnTheWallTableView) {
    NSDictionary *propertyItems = [self.repliesItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *text = [self.postItems objectForKey:@"text"];

    NSLog(@"%@", text);

    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(280, MAXFLOAT);

    CGSize sizeText = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    self.height = MAX(sizeText.height, 44.0f);

    self.photosArray = [propertyItems objectForKey:@"attach_photos"];
    self.videosArray = [propertyItems objectForKey:@"attach_videos"];

    if((self.photosArray.count == 0) && (self.videosArray.count == 0)) {

        height += (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2);

    } else if ((self.videosArray.count > 0) && (self.photosArray.count == 0)) {

        height += 90 + (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2);

    } else if((self.photosArray.count > 0) && (self.videosArray.count == 0)) {

        height += 85 + (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2);
    }

}
```

Now, if the text is quite small, it fits the row well, and the row is resizes. Such as this:
[image]

But, after the text comes bigger, this what happening:

[image]

[image]

Obviously I don't need the scrolling right there, and I would disable it. But the thing here is that it takes the size of the text, and it resize the label, you can see how many space it make from the top and from the bottom of the label. But it don't put actual text there. Another thing is that it didn't resize the TableView it self, when I'm trying to resize it, I get the overlapping of the bottom table by the middle table.

**Can anyone recommend any solution of this, or maybe another way of implementation?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using UITableView for the first and second view? The first one is just a button that looks like a table row, second one is just a text view, so why do you complicate your life? :-)

Comment: In second one I need to display a row, because there would be images and videos as well.

Comment: The videos and images still doesn't make it a table. Sorry for being off-topic but I cannot focus on technical details when the design seems to be so much off.

Comment: I have already custom cell, that would display images and videos there, I'm already using it. Although I remove the first tableview, and make just a button, but I need to display the cell, in the second one.

Comment: The design choice also makes your life harder for that resizeable view as you will need to set the height of both the UITableView and the UITableViewCell to be the height of your text.

Comment: @ChrisH Can you recommend something, how can I avoid use of the second table? Or how could I implement this?

Comment: It's tricky to design your application from here, but if you're not using the UITableView for it's main function (ie. display lots of similar rows of data), then perhaps use something more appropriate - your own UIView sub-class, a UITextField, or perhaps a UILabel. As your text size changes you will still need to alter the frames of each View appropriately. TBH, I think managing arbitrarily sized text fields to be a real pain in iOS.

Comment: @ChrisH Ok. I changed the whoel design of the ViewController. Now it is working perfectly. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can do this is use tableviewDelegate method for setting cell height according your text like this for example:

This method will be called for every cell to decide how much cell should have height

```
  - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    NSString *strDetails = [yourTextArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   //if(indexPath.row == 1)
   //{
     CGSize stringSize = [strDetails sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Marker Felt" size:13] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(320, 9999) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap]; // Provide text as well as font name in which your text will be displayed and constrainedToSize which defines width and height it should be maximum
     return stringSize.height+65; //Here 65 can be any value depending on Calculation  ImageView height + uppermost space + bottom space added
   //}
   //else 
   //{
   //  return 80 // anything u wishes
   //}
 }
```